# What's the best way to version API code in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, versioning

I have created a set of API and need to version them.  Due to the lack of namespace in Objective-C import, I have resorted to using a rather clunky way of naming the API file names using suffix 1_0, 1_1, etc.  The different version of API code need to co-exist in the same project as the code decides in runtime which version to use based on the client.

Is there a better way to do this?

e.g.

Authentication API

```
XXAuthAPI1_0.h / XXAuthAPI1_0.m
XXAuthAPI1_1.h / XXAuthAPI1_1.m
```

Comment: If the backward compatibility is so bad that you need two completely separate implementations, then this is probably the only solution. If the number of differences is small, then there are probably better ways to achieve this.

Comment: It's fine to do this internally, but I'd do what Apple does for there GL wrapper and provide a uniform interface that can initialize one of the versioned backends.